# Limit costs for AWS EC2 instances based on a budget

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a monthly budget we are alowed to spend on experimental computing tasks. At the moment we use docker machine to autoscale the computing power. But this has a high risk of exceeding our budget.

Our plan is, to tag the instances used for the computing tasks e.g. `comp_task` and then create a max budget with a filter for this tag. But as I figured, there is only the option to get an Email, if the budget is exeeded.

Is there a way, to terminate/forbid further EC2 instances using the "budgeted tag" when the limit is exeeded? Or is there another way of achieving the same?

Comment: No. Write a lambda to terminate resources once you hit your limit, or use cloud custodian. You should also automate turning them off outside business hours.

Answer (score 0):

you can setup a cloudwatch alarm for the billing that send a notification to a notification group. After that you can use a lambda watching that topic to trigger the deletion or termination of the instances.

Please refer to the AWS docs below.

[Creating a Billing Alarm to Monitor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html)

[Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html)